# Extracting String from HTML source

Tags: java, html, string

Hi want to extract String between HTML Tags from a source code but I am getting an error by using the code given below. Could someone help me with the reason for error?

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/\<body[^>]*\>([^]*)\<\/body/");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s1);
while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println( "Found value: " + matcher.group(1).trim() );
}
```

The error I am getting is: "Invalid escape sequence"

Thanks

Comment: Don't parse HTML using regex. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't parse html files with regex. I suggest you to use `jsoup` parser.

```
String html = "<html><body><h1> Hello, World! </h1></body></html>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
String text = doc.body().text();
System.out.println(text);
```

Output:

```
Hello, World!
```

Comment: Thanks Avinash. Appreciate it

Comment: Since you're new to StackOverflow, i suggest you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)